# Constant CPU usage without cause

Tags: windows-7, cpu

For a few days now, my computer uses a constant 30-35% CPU time, even if I don't use any program, and the mouse pointer shows a spinning circle next to the arrow.

I checked the Task Manager and Process Explorer. They both show 80-85% idle time but the usage is constant at 35%. How can I find out what is eating the CPU if PE and TM shows nothing?

If you check this screenshot, you can see that nothing is using more than 5%, yet my computer is on fire.
[image]

Comment: The task page on Process Explorer has a total CPU graph and hovering the mouse over it shows what is using the highest CPU load at any time.

Comment: It shows that the each CPU core uses 45% and the highest process is MsMpEng.exe with 4,5%. How can it be 45%?

Comment: Sounds like a buggy driver.

Comment: I could be a driver loop which is consuming CPU time without its being allocated to any of the running tasks. A clue might be if the **Interrupts** line is showing activity. If it is rogue hardware, then power off completely, removing the power lead and disconnect the battery if it's a laptop. Allow 10 seconds without power before rebooting. Also, have a look at http://techat-jack.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/solved-high-cpu-usage-of-microsoft.html

Comment: It's worked for years without any problem and no new devices are added. What driver would cause the problem?

Comment: Notably this caused by a HDD that is constantly trying to write data but  failing.  Your screenshots indicate your CPU is NOT idile

Comment: Process Explorers says: System Idle Process System Idle Process 81.18 0 K 24 K 0

Comment: follow this and give me the file: http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this solution seems to have solved the issue: http://techat-jack.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/solved-high-cpu-usage-of-microsoft.html

1. Run Task Manager, find the process with high CPU usage. (Sorting by CPU may help you find it)
2. Likely you will find "MsMpEng.exe" has taken much of your CPU time
3. Now go to  your Microsoft Security Essentials, click on the "Settings" tab.              Select "Excluded files and locations"
4. Browse to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Client\MsMpEng.exe", Ok and press Add button to add the file to your list of excluded files and locations. Press Save changes button.

Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run **perfmon /report** as an administrator on Powershell. This will produce a complete report of what is what on your OS.

System Disk I/O values could tell a thing or two. Apart from this search for unusual values on each section of the report as the report is pretty helpful on this by letting you know the mean value on each category.

I suppose that this is a physical machine and not a VM. In the latter case the key could be on the Hypervisor.

Finally, have you checked that your computer is clear of viruses,worms etc?

Comment: I did it and it shows only 1 warning: Interrupts (interrupt/s) 23,634 23,013 25,222

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, constantly 30-35% CPU usage even if I wasn´t connected to the internet! I followed all advices I could get, but nothing changed.
So, I decided to run CCleaner (free program). And when you run CCleaner you must turn your internet browser off, otherwise CCleaner asks if you allow CCleaner to turn it off.

Since I know this, I do not have any browser open while running CCleaner. However, CCleaner asked me anyway If it should turn off Firefox! I was puzzled, because Firefox wasn´t open... But I clicked "yes", and CCleaner tried to close Firefox to no avail, CCleaner asked again, "This application is difficult to close. Dou you want to force it to close"?. I never had this question before, but again I clicked "yes".

And, bang... the CPU was down to 0-1% !!! So, in my case Firefox obviously ran some programs or had browsers open that wasn´t shown on the screen! Very, very strange...

Hope this can help!

Best regards/
Markus